# Amazonka: How to generate S3:// uri from Network.AWS.S3.Types.Object?

Tags: haskell, amazon-s3

I've been using [turtle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle) to call "aws s3 ls" and I'm trying to figure out how to replace that with [amazonka](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/amazonka).

Absolute s3 urls were central to how my program worked. I now know how to get objects and filter them, but I don't know how to convert an object to an S3 url to integrate with my existing program.

I came across the [getFile](https://github.com/brendanhay/amazonka/blob/4fdd746346323aac7de6e82752b16609ef0bf212/examples/src/Example/S3.hs#L65) function and tried downloading a file from s3.

Perhaps I had something wrong, but it didn't seem like just the S3 Bucket and S3 Object key were enough to download a given file. If I'm wrong about that I need to double check my configuration.